# Program crashes by "out string"

Tags: c#

I am using this dll where one of the methods expects string as an argument by out, i.e.

```
void function(out string param);
```

When I am passing the string by out, the program crashes. I am using C#.
The output I am getting in output debug window of VS2010 is as follows:
The program '[4116] Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).

The problem is sudden and short so I don't know how to explain further, but if you have further questions let me know...

Update:
This is ActiveX dll and I came across the tutorial mentioning that COM returns string in Unicode. Is that what is causing the problem?

Comment: Do you have the C code available or the DLLImport declaration?

Comment: `0xc0000005` is an access violation.  Typically you would use a `StringBuilder` with a known size as an output buffer for a native function, not a `string`.  So you have the C code?  It would help us get you an answer.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand "Do you have the C code?". What I have from the company is the actual dll that I am linking through the references in Solution Explorer, I have their demo code and their documentation. Their demo code makes use of Visual C++ 6.0 and I think they are using MFC.

Comment: Also, when I am using their dll I have to turn Embed Interop types to false so that I can actually use classes and their methods.

Answer (score 1):

How to debug:

This seem to be issue with native/managed interop. So make sure your VS debugger is set to mixed (native/managed) for x86 or purely native for x64.

Turn off "My code only" (Options->Debug) and turn on Debug->Exceptions-> when thrown for native exceptions.

This way you'll have stack and see what is going on.

Note: Having source for C and C# parts could avoid need to debug...

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling it, are you including the 'out' word in your method call?

```
string str;
function(out str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ed S above.  Try using a StringBuilder since you are passing arguments between managed and nonmanaged code.  Unfortunately, you wont get too far debugging it since you dont have the native code.

Comment: I created StringBuilder, converted it into string and passed it as out but the same error

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem with a C# application talking to a C++ application but I could not get it to crash the same way.  Sorry about that.  I wish I could help you more.